# Using ee.Image.paint() with Geometry

Tags: google-earth-engine, geometry-conversion

https://code.earthengine.google.com/51d66ca06d0b08dbb5a7f19c10817252

Using theese Lines wont result in a Image with the Line Painted on it

`var Line =ee.FeatureCollection(geometry)
var Pimage = ee.Image(0).paint(Line,ee.Number(100),ee.Number(10000))
Map.addLayer(Pimage)`

in the Documentation it says following:

`ee.Image.paint(featureCollection, color, width)`

**this:image (Image):**

The image on which the collection is painted.

**featureCollection (FeatureCollection):**

The collection painted onto the image.

**color (Object, default: 0):**

Either the name of a color property or a number.

**width (Object, default: null):**

Either the name of a line-width property or a number.

I do not understand why no line is painted in `Pimage`, since I have converted the `ee.Geometry` to a `ee.FeatureCollection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a transparent image to paint the feature collection on to make it visible.
See an example in this Google Earth Engine examples repository: [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/972f0d3f6a14d1c3a910840d22ea504c).

For your case, you will need te following code:

```
var Line =ee.FeatureCollection(geometry); print(Line)
var Pimage = ee.Image().paint(Line,0,5)
Map.addLayer(Pimage, {max: 3, palette: ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue']});
Map.centerObject(geometry)
```

You can set the color number based on the palette in the Map.addLayer, or define a color yourself in the paint call: [Link script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0da90375e4d28d34c0bfdf5e785f3496)